# Android: kernel to user threads mapping relation

Tags: android, multithreading

Anybody know where I can learn about if this relationship is one-to-one, one-to-many, or a mixture of those (such as one-to-one for the UI thread and many-to-many for the others)?

Comment: Book on android threading [here](http://amzn.com/1449364136). I believe everything you want to know is in the initial chapters:  http://amzn.com/1449364136   I almost picked this book up when I saw it on the store shelf the other day. Maybe another day.

Comment: Ok, pretty good suggestion.  The book didn't 100% state it in the terms I need it, but I was able to infer this:  it's a one-to-one relationship because the book mentions that each thread created is in it's base form, a Linux PThread.