# How do Android threads map to kernel threads?

Tags: java, android, linux, linux-kernel

Not in precise terms a programming question, but don't know a better place to ask this, so here goes: How do Android threads map to kernel threads?

If I create a thread in Android, does it spawn an equivalent kernel thread? I found this link : http://www.wideskills.com/android/intrprocess-communication/threads-in-android, but am not able to understand what this guy is saying

As a follow up, if I start too many `AsyncTasks` (which internally work by spawning JAVA threads), how would it spawn the corresponding threads in kernel? Would there be a one-to-one or a many-to-one mapping?

Comment: Kernel threads are automatically spawned when you start your *java / user* threads. There will usually be a 1 to 1 mapping between User level threads and kernel level threads. That's why it is said that *for best performance use as many threads as the number of logical processors in your PC*

Comment: So, lets say, that I spawn 1000 asyncTask, would there be a 1000 kernel threads spawned as well? (It is quite easy to spawn 1000 asynctask, especially if one is working on loading images)

Comment: Answer would perhaps vary from implementation to implementation. But I think, the answer would be "no" for this particular case. There is always an upperbound on how many threads can be created at the kernel level. The same kernel level threads are re-used.

Comment: Useful link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791801/how-do-user-level-threads-ults-and-kernel-level-threads-klts-differ-with-reg?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584557/android-kernel-to-user-threads-mapping-relation) was answered saying there is a 1-to-1 mapping from kernel threads to `Thread` objects. However, the [Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) state that an `AsyncTask` object states that "tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors", which is 1-to-many.

So if you spawn 1000 `AsyncTasks`, you will have 1 kernel thread running 1 user `Thread` that is running 1000 `AsyncTasks`. So you can safely spawn tons of `AsyncTasks` without worrying about efficiency, thread-wise.